# How to migrate/update a SQLite database stored on a Docker volume

Tags: docker, sqlite

I am new on Docker. I have a Docker app with a SQLite database stored on a Docker volume, in order to persist the data.

Because a new app requirement, I have to update the database schema but I don't know how to do it.

Which is the correct way to execute the sql update command before to deploy the new app version?

EDIT: I would like to do it with Docker, using app version number or something like that.

EDIT2: The app is Python coded.

Comment: In general one would use a migration library to do this. They will be written in your language of choice e.g. Python, PHP, Java, etc. What do you use?

Comment: I have used Python to code the app

Comment: OK, search for "Python migration library". Learning about migrations is generally worthwhile - you need to ensure that when you deploy the new version of the code, that it can cope with the old database format, since code update and migration run tend to happen at different times. In other words, make sure your app does not break during the period when the code has updated but the migration has not yet been run.

Comment: Data isn't stored *inside* a container, it's stored on the host [and accessed through volumes or bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/). Otherwise, each time the container stopped the data would be lost.

Comment: Is this a server application or an app on the user's computer (e.g. an Electron app)?

Comment: It is a Flask server